# How can I specify library dependencies using SystemJS?

Tags: javascript, amd, commonjs, systemjs, es6-module-loader

Using [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), how do I specify that one library depends on another?  For example, the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) JavaScript library depends on [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).  Based on the [SytemJS docs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#shim-dependencies), I assumed I would specify this dependency using `System.config.meta` property:

```
System.config({
    baseUrl: './scripts',
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    map: {
        jquery: './lib/jquery-2.2.0.min.js',
        bootstrap: './lib/bootstrap.min.js'
    },
    meta: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});
System.import('./scripts/app.js');
```

But this seems to have no effect.  When I run my application, the Bootstrap library throws a `Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` error - which means Bootstrap is being loaded before jQuery.

How can I ensure that jQuery is always loaded before Bootstrap?

Comment: jQuery needs to be added to `window` explicitly.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter - can you provide an example?  I'm not sure what that means in the context of SystemJS.

Comment: `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jQuery')`, put that code anywhere before the inclusion of the bootstrap files. It's ugly, but that's the way Twitter likes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After blindly changing things, I happened upon a configuration that seems to work.  Here's my config:

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: './scripts/lib/jquery-2.2.0.min.js',
        bootstrap: './scripts/lib/bootstrap.min.js'
    },
    meta: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});

System.import('./scripts/app.js');
```

I think the key was changing from `map` to `paths`.

**EDIT**

Side note: after learning a bit more about SystemJS, I'm discovering that it is **much** easier to let [jspm](http://jspm.io/) do the hard work of managing my SystemJS configuration.

Comment: This not work at me. I'm trying to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528718/how-to-globally-import-javascript-library-in-angular2-typescript-project

Comment: If `jquery` is in `node_modules`, then this works =>  `...paths:{jquery:'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'}...`